# How to join https to a text using urljoin?

Tags: python, urllib3

I am trying to add `https` to a text `business.com` as follows:

```
from urllib.request import urljoin
datax = "business.com"
base_url = "https://www."
aa11 = urljoin(base_url, datax)
print(aa11)
```

I get the following. Actually, I don't know to avoid adding `/` between `.` and `business`.

```
https://www./business.com
```

Desired output:

```
https://www.business.com
```

Or Is there anyother way to get the desired output?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not seem a promising solution but will work as `https:// (or http://)` part is common in most of the websites i.e why below code will work

include this line above print `aa11 = aa11[:8]+aa11[8:].replace('/',"")`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use basic string concatenation, which gives you the exact output you want here?

```
datax = "business.com"
base_url = "https://www."
x = base_url+datax
print(x)
```